# Recommended HTML5 Outline Section

Tags: html

Following this guide [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document).  Which one between these two is preferable and more recommended way for doing HTML5?

'#1

```
<h1>Continents</h1>
<section>
    <h1>Europe</h1>
    <section>
        <h1>South Europe</h1>
        <p>...</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>East Europe</h1>
        <p>...</p>
    </section>
</section>
...
```

'#2

```
<h1>Continents</h1>
<section>
    <h2>Europe</h2>
    <section>
        <h3>Southern Europe</h3>
        <p>...</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Eastern Europe</h3>
        <p>...</p>
    </section>
</section>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples are perfectly semantically valid. You may want to prefer to use the latter example as `h1` to `h6` elements are ranked (as defined in [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) and [this more in-depth section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections) within the HTML5 specification).

Due to this ranking, placing a `h2` as the start tag within a `section` *may imply* that the heading isn't as important to that section as a `h1` element. But this is entirely interpreted by the user (and, I suppose, search engines - but this isn't a question about SEO, fortunately).

> #### 4.3.6 The h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 elements
>
> These elements have a rank given by the number in their name. The h1 element is said to have the highest rank, the h6 element has the lowest rank, and two elements with the same name have equal rank.

> #### 4.3.10 Headings and sections
>
> The first element of heading content in an element of sectioning content represents the heading for that section. Subsequent headings of equal or higher rank start new (implied) sections, headings of lower rank start implied subsections that are part of the previous one. In both cases, the element represents the heading of the implied section.

At any rate, if you start off with a `h1` you can potentially have down to 5 levels of sub-sections (`h2` to `h6`), whereas if you start off with a `h3` you can only have 3 (`h4`, `h5` and `h6`).

Comment: And if it's from SEO perspective, Are these two really have a difference then?